# Отобразить текст по центру в Google Charts Timeline

Tags: javascript, google-chart, timeline

Мне нужно отобразить текст по центру в Google Charts Timeline.

[image: вот тут]

Нашел в документации свойства `timeline.barLabelStyle` и `timeline.rowLabelStyle`, но там можно редактировать только размер текста и шрифт.

Как отобразить текст по центру в Google Charts Timeline?